# Heroku app crash H10 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to get a site up and running on heroku, like I've done a million times before, however this time it keeps crashing.  Amongst all the code, this line sticks out, but I don't see the problem

```
app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/concerns/challenges_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `challenges_controller' for main:Object (NameError)
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+0
```

Here are the rest of the logs:

```
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151051+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151051+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151051+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.151320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152064+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-01-29T02:26:41.152345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-01-29T02:26:42.695112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-29T02:26:42.729083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-29T02:26:32.395259+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 379b025 by micahsherman@mac.com
2014-01-29T02:26:32.424844+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by micahsherman@mac.com
2014-01-29T02:27:14.919483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=evening-beach-2320.herokuapp.com request_id=bda7828c-d27b-4997-ad87-54b9a62871ef fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-29T02:27:18.194917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=evening-beach-2320.herokuapp.com request_id=9da3186b-5fcc-40d6-89d2-f37cc4c5d805 fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-29T02:27:18.466080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-beach-2320.herokuapp.com request_id=36b89deb-931a-43a2-8500-ef9261e98e6b fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-29T02:34:44+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-29T02:35:17.955599+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy fd72b3e by micahsherman@mac.com
2014-01-29T02:35:17.996771+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by micahsherman@mac.com
2014-01-29T02:35:18+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-01-29T02:35:18.258295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-01-29T02:35:20.938333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 43382 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2014-01-29T02:35:23.721899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-29T02:35:23.721899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43382
2014-01-29T02:35:23.721899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.721899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-01-29T02:35:23.721899+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/concerns/challenges_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `challenges_controller' for main:Object (NameError)
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-01-29T02:35:23.723229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-01-29T02:35:24.859451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-01-29T02:35:24.870209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-29T02:35:35.682605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-beach-2320.herokuapp.com request_id=b97e3a13-c2c8-4530-b3f0-8267c61877d8 fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-29T02:35:40.568613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=evening-beach-2320.herokuapp.com request_id=84274d6a-7720-4795-853e-69d407eae0cd fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

And here is the controller that threw an error :

```
class ChallengesController < ApplicationController
    def show
    end
end
```

database.yml :

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

gem 'annotate'

gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

ruby "1.9.3"
```

Comment: that's not what threw the error, unless your controller is in your concerns folder (which it shouldn't be).

Comment: @sevenseacat You are a scholar and a gentleman.  That was it!  Ladies and gentlman... I am a big dumb animal.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your ChallengesController, hence this line

```
2014-01-29T02:35:23.722438+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/concerns/challenges_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `challenges_controller' for main:Object (NameError)
```